# an if statement with a variable as a condition and the variable can have multiple possibilities

Tags: python-3.x

```
print("Welcome to your phones Troubleshooter")
issue = input(str("Does your phone have an issue?"))
if [issue == "yes", "Yes", "YES"]:
```

I've set up parameters for three options of yes but it doesn't seem to work it just keeps going to my else statement. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
print("Welcome to your phones Troubleshooter")
issue = input(str("Does your phone have an issue?"))
if issue.lower() == "yes":
  print("There is an issue")
```

or a slight change in your code's if statement:

```
 print("Welcome to your phones Troubleshooter")
 issue = input(str("Does your phone have an issue?"))
 if issue == "yes" or issue == "Yes" or issue == "YES":
      print("There is an issue")
```

You should read the [if-statement](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html) syntax. You are doing in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Welcome to your phones Troubleshooter")
issue = input(str("Does your phone have an issue?"))

accepted_string = {"yes", "Yes", "YES"}

if issue in accepted_string:
  print("Found it")
else:
  print("Not found")
```